# Validate a date is not between an array of range of dates

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to validate this:

*"A person can not take vacations on a certain range of dates if that date has already been taken"*

So, if I have something like this in a table **vacations**

```
start_date  |  end_date  | duration_days | user_id
--------------------------------------------------
 01-01-2019 | 01-02-2019 |      30       |   1
 03-02-2019 | 28-02-2019 |      15       |   2
 12-12-2019 | 01-01-2020 |      20       |   3
```

As you can see, all range of **dates are mutually exclusive**

And If I wanted to add one more row, I must validate this (I think so, If I'm wrong, please correct me):

- `start_date` is **not in**:

  [{01-01-2019; 01-02-2019}, {03-02-2019; 28-02-2019}, {03-02-2019; 28-02-2019}].
- `end_date` is **not in**:

  [{01-01-2019; 01-02-2019}, {03-02-2019; 28-02-2019}, {03-02-2019; 28-02-2019}].

Taking all this logic to **laravel**, in a **VacationController** store:

```
public function store(Request $request, $user_id)
{
        $dates_taken = Vacation::all('start_date', 'end_date');

        $request->validate([
            'start_date' => 'required|date|not_in:'.$dates_taken,
            'end_date' => 'required|date|not_in:'.$dates_taken',
        ]);
}
```

I know that validation is wrong, but I wanted to understand the problem.

There is some way to do this with [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom validation and can define your custom rule using `Validator::extend()` like:

```
Validator::extend('exclude_pre_leaves', function ($attribute, $value, $p, $validator) {
    $data = $validator->getData();
    $hasMached = Vacation::where('start_date', '>=', $data[$p[0]])
                            ->where('end_date','<=', $data[$p[0]])
                            ->orWhere(function($q) use($p, $data){
                                        $q->where('start_date', '>=', $data[$p[1]])
                                          ->where('end_date','<=', $data[$p[1]]);
                            })->count();

    return $hasMatched == 0;
});
```

And you can use this like:

```
$request->validate([
    'start_date' => 'required|date|exclude_pre_leaves:start_date,end_date',
    'end_date' => 'required|date|exclude_pre_leaves:start_date,end_date'
]);
```

Comment: You can change the condition as per your requirements.

Comment: I have updated solution to add validation with range. Please verify.

Comment: @L.flor let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have to create the `Validator::extend` into the store function into the controller?

Comment: Better to place this in `AppServiceProvider > boot` function so you can reuse anywhere else if needed.

Comment: I tried but won't work. You have some writing errors but it's ok, I'm not getting errors but it does not validate

Comment: What's the issue now?

Comment: I think the conditions of the `where` are not being effective, because when try to register another row just simply skip the validation. I'm checking the `where` clauses to see if there's an error in it

Comment: @VikashPathak I fixed it too in the code and it's all ok about syntax

Comment: For example, can you please add the values for start& end date that should be false. So I can verify that too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195003/discussion-between-vikash-pathak-and-l-flor).

Answer (score 2):

There is Option to creating our own rules so

> `php artisan make:rule VacationDateRule`

This Will create the new file with name

`VacationDateRule.php` inside `App\Rules` Directory

After that I am Considering Your Model As **Vacation**

Copy and Paste the Rule File

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Vacation;

class VacationDateRule implements Rule
{
    public $from;
    public $to;
    public $userid;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($form ,$to ,$userid)
    {
        $this->form = $form; 
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->userid = $userid;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $vacation = Vacation::where('start_date','>=',$this->form)
                            ->where('end_date','<=',$this->to)->count();
        $vacation === 0 ? true : false ;
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

and in the validation

```
 $request->validate([
        'start_date' => ['required|date',new VacationDateRule(
            $request->start_date,
            $request->start_date,
            $request->user_id)],
        'end_date' => 'required|date',
    ]);
```

If you have any issues kindly comment below

Comment: Is there a way to use `foreach` into the validator so I might be able to validate all the taken dates

Comment: you don't need the foreach as the query select all the data greater that `start_date `and all data less than `end_date` and count it

Comment: I got it. I'm on it

Comment: I tried this but had to use the @Vikash's answer, thanks a lot. You can check this that I used as condition stackoverflow.com/questions/…

Answer (score 0):

Use your own validation as you want. implement your own algorithm in validation

```
 $validationarray = $this->validate($request,
            [
                'start_date'  => [
                    'required',
                    'date',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) { 
                        //$attribute->input name, $value for that value.
                        //or your own way to collect data. then check.
                        //make your own condition.
                        if($this->dateBetween($value)) {                        
                             $fail($attribute.' is failed custom rule. The date is not acceptable.');
                        }
                    },          
                ],    
                'end_date'  => [
                    'required',
                    'date',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) { 
                        //$attribute->input name, $value for that value.
                        //or your own way to collect data. then check.
                        //make your own condition.
                        if($this->dateBetween($value)) {                        
                             $fail($attribute.' is failed custom rule. The date is not acceptable.');
                        }
                    },          
                ],   
            ]);
```

Write the function to same class. Cause I used it for validation.

```
public function dateBetween($date){
    if(checkDateAsDesired) return true;
    else return false;   
}
```